# sql query to get sum of row value

Tags: mysql

my query getting o/p like this

```
partyname    bjp      aap         congress   

votes        1        2              2
```

**but i also need sum of row. below is my expected output.**

**all the partyname and votes comes from database and it is dynamic.**

for ex

```
 BJP         aap           congress       total

  1             2            2             5


<?php                
$sqltoatl = "SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, COUNT( RES.CONSTITUENCY )
    AS VOTESCOUNT FROM voter_count RES JOIN (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX( VOTES )
    AS VOTES FROM voter_count GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY)MAXS USING ( VOTES, CONSTITUENCY )
    GROUP BY PARTYNAME LIMIT 0 , 1000";

$resulttoatl = mysql_query($sqltoatl);

while ($rowtoatl = mysql_fetch_array($resulttoatl,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>  

<th><?php echo $rowtoatl['PARTYNAME']; ?></th>      
<td><?php echo $rowtoatl['VOTESCOUNT']; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your database schema I don't quite understand the reason for the complicated vote calculation you're doing.

Maybe I'm missing something, but if what you want is a number of votes per party and a total then maybe something like this is what you want?

```
SELECT PARTYNAME, SUM(votes) AS VOTES FROM voter_count GROUP BY Partyname
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(VOTES) AS VOTES FROM voter_count;
```

It could look like this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e9cc/3)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT p.partyId, p.partyName, COUNT(IFNULL(v.bjp,0)) bjpTotal, COUNT(IFNULL(v.aap,0)) aapTotal, COUNT(IFNULL(v.congress,0)) congressTotal, 
      (COUNT(IFNULL(v.bjp,0)) + COUNT(IFNULL(v.aap,0)) + COUNT(IFNULL(v.congress,0))) partyTotal
FROM parties p
LEFT JOIN votes v
    ON p.partyId = v.partyId
GROUP BY p.partyId, p.partyName
```

Comment: sir but my partyname is not fix it comes different from database and also votes comes from database

Comment: Namrehs you need to explain things a little bit, don't just throw out code